# warning c4996 See online help for details

Tags: c, visual-c++

warning C4996: 'getch': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _getch.

Comment: Ok, seems pretty self explanatory.  What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

This compiler warning indicates that there is a reference to the 'getch()' function in the code.  The compiler is suggesting that the code be updated to use the '_getch()' function instead.

Generally, this error will occur in a Microsoft development environment.  ***Way back***, a long time ago, Microsoft introduced the 'getch()' [and 'getche()'] functions.  These functions would wait for the user to press a key, and then retun that key character back to the caller.  The 'getch()' function would not 'echo' the key back to the (DOS or early Windows) screen, while 'getche()' would echo the key pressed to the screen.

The 'getch()' and 'getche()' functions were not adopted by other environments, such as *nix.  Eventually, Microsoft elected to rename the functions with a leading underscore to help identify their proprietary (Microsoft) nature.

By the look of the error message, I assume that the '_getch()' function has been adopted by the "ISO C++" standard.  (However, I don't do C++ as it is an abomination to many C programmers such as myself).

Note: The *nix 'curses' library also sports a getch() which is somewhat similar to the old Microsoft function.

The compiler warning noted in the question is just that; a warning.  Most likely, code will still compile and run (in a Microsoft environment).

Comment: `_getch()` is not specifically named in C++11, however names beginning with an underscore are reserved for use by the compiler as a name in the global namespace. (Meaning that non-standard compiler extensions should take this form, and user code should not take this form).

Answer (score 1):

If you actually look in the Windows header source for this sort of stuff, you'll see that these symbols are not actually "Deprecated". It's rather silly for MS to do this and making porting applications yet even more annoying by issuing these warnings.

You'll want to add `/D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` to ignore those warnings. There's virtually nothing you can do about them other than something silly like `#define _foo foo`